# What does `while list and list[-1]` mean in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

```
class Solution:
    def nextGreaterElements(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        n = len(nums)
        nge = [-1] * n
        st = []

        for i in range(2 * n - 1, -1, -1):
            while st and st[-1] <= nums[i % n]:   # <=== THIS LINE!
                st.pop()

            if i < n:
                if st:
                    nge[i] = st[-1]
            st.append(nums[i % n])
        return nge
```

Can someone tell me what does `while st and st[-1]` mean? Can a list and element can be used in `and`?

Comment: You're not parsing it properly.  It's `while st and (st[-1] <= nums[i % n]):`.  They want to test the last value in `st`, but you can't do that if the list is empty.  If the list is empty, `st` is false, so it skips the loop.  That loop deletes all the items at the end of the list that are less than the `nums` value.

Comment: *can a list and element can be used in AND*  Yes, it can. The value will be evaluated as truthful or falsely.

Comment: while `st` -> if list is not None and some value present in it, `st[-1]` tell the last value

Comment: I assume those asterisks are for highlighting? You really need to consider the full operation including the `<= nums[i % n]` part.

Comment: please clean up the example, use  a python comment like `while ... # <== THIS LINE` to highlight the line you want.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially, the expression asks if the list has something in it, and if so, is its last member less than another value. You couldn't check just `st[-1] <= nums[i % n]` without running the risk that the list is empty, raising an error.

`while st and st[-1] <= nums[i % n]:` has a boolean `and` plus a `<=` comparison. From the [Operator prescience chart](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) we see that `<=` binds more tightly than `and`. But [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) evaluate left to right and short-circuit, returning the last calculated value, when found not true.

So, python first checks `bool(st)`. A list is `True` if it has 1 or more member. If empty, the expression is complete, `while` sees `False` and exits. If non-empty, python looks at  `st[-1] <= nums[i % n]`. `st[-1]` is that last member of the list and the result of the comparison terminates the boolean `and` conditional and is returned to the `while`.